# Force a Jenkins pipeline job to pull a new private image from Dockerhub

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to pull a new version of a specific private image with a specific tag on Docker Hub using the Jenkins Docker pipeline plugin.  The Docker shell commands would look like:

```
docker login -u user -p password
docker pull user/foo:bar
```

Something like this seems like it ought to work:

```
node () {
    image = docker.image('user/foo:bar')
    image.pull()
    image.inside {
        // Commands to run in the container
```

But there's no way to execute the login step, so I always get the error:

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for user/foo, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
```

I've gone through the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) and the [code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin), but the documentation doesn't even mention pulling and the examples in the code don't show how to log in to pull a private image.  I can manually script it but the whole point of using the Docker pipeline plugin is to avoid directly scripting Docker commands.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe what you will need here is the `withRegistry` function.
It can be used as follows

```
docker.withRegistry('<registry-url>', '<credential-id>') {
    image = docker.image('user/foo:bar')
    image.pull()
}
```

Everything within the `withRegistry` block will use that registry and authentication for pulling the image.

Where the `<registry-url>` in this case is the URL for the Dockerhub registry. I believe the Dockerhub registry URL is `https://registry.hub.docker.com`

The `<credential-id>` is the ID of the Dockerhub credentials stored in Jenkins.

To add these credentials navigate from the Jenkins index page to `Credentials -> System -> Global credentials -> Add Credentials`.

Once on this page you will need to select `Kind` as `Username with password`.
The scope should be `Global`.
The `username` and `password` fields are your username and password for Dockerhub.

The `ID` field is whatever text you want to be the `<credential-id>`. For example if you make the `ID` field `docker-hub-credentials` that will need to be the second argument to `withRegistry`.

Here is an example of what the page to add credentials could look like.
[image]

Comment: I tried withRegistry with that Dockerhub URL and several other Dockerhub URLs, and I could never manage to get it to log into Dockerhub correctly.  I used this pretty much as presented here.  Is there something else I needed to do?

Comment: @ceridwen Did you add your Dockerhub credentials in Jenkins ?

Comment: Yeah, I did.  With docker login I even managed to successfully pull, it's just I never managed to get withRegistry() to work.

Comment: Could you show exactly how you are calling withRegistry ?

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: For some reason this works now, when it didn't before.  Thanks!